# Inner Join on multiple id's if they are not null

Tags: sql, database, join, hive

I've been having some trouble creating a join that captures the following records. I have spent about 5 hours yesterday trying to figure it out, but could not.

I have two tables, **Table A** and **Table B**
Both these tables have the following columns:

```
ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ID_4
```

Now, I need to create a join between both tables so that the result pulls records on matching IDs that are not null, and if more than 1 ID matches, then I use all IDs that match to pull up the record, so there are a couple scenarios:

Scenario 1: All IDs in both tables match perfectly (this is easy to code)

**Here I would join by All ID'S.**

```
+--------+---------+---------+--------+
| A.ID_1 |  A.ID_2 |  A.ID_3 | A.ID_4 |
+--------+---------+---------+--------+
| CAD    |   AAPL  |     853 |    200 |
+--------+---------+---------+--------+

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| B.ID_1 | B.ID_2 | B.ID_3 | B.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    | AAPL   |    853 |    200 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Scenario 2: One or more  ID matches in both tables, the rest are NULL (also easy)

**Here I would join by ID_1 and ID_3 only.**

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| A.ID_1 | A.ID_2 | A.ID_3 | A.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    | NULL   |    933 | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| B.ID_1 | B.ID_2 | B.ID_3 | B.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    | NULL   |    933 | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Scenario 3: One or more ID's match in the tables but some don't

**Here I need to join on only ID_1 and ID_2, as ID_3 and ID_4 are NULL for respective tables.**

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| A.ID_1 | A.ID_2 | A.ID_3 | A.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  TSLA  |    341 | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| B.ID_1 | B.ID_2 | B.ID_3 | B.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  TSLA  |  NULL  |    250 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Scenario 4: All ID's have NULL, therefore record is rejected

So if 
**Table A contained the following:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| A.ID_1 | A.ID_2 | A.ID_3 | A.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  AAPL  |  853   |   200  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    | NULL   |  933   | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| CAD    |  TSLA  |  341   | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| NULL   |  NULL  |  NULL  | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Table B contained the following:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| B.ID_1 | B.ID_2 | B.ID_3 | B.ID_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  AAPL  |  853   |   200  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  NULL  |  933   |  NULL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| CAD    |  TSLA  |  NULL  |   250  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| NULL   |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Result would be:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID_1   | ID_2   | ID_3   | ID_4   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  AAPL  |  853   |   200  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CAD    |  NULL  |  933   |  NULL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+ 
| CAD    |  TSLA  |  341   |  NULL  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this? There is always someone who writes shorter code... :-)

```
WITH directMatch AS (
    SELECT
        A.*
    FROM
        A
        INNER JOIN B
            -- exclude scenario 4
            ON (
                A.ID_1 IS NOT NULL
                OR A.ID_2 IS NOT NULL
                OR A.ID_3 IS NOT NULL
                OR A.ID_4 IS NOT NULL
            )
            AND (
                B.ID_1 IS NOT NULL
                OR B.ID_2 IS NOT NULL
                OR B.ID_3 IS NOT NULL
                OR B.ID_4 IS NOT NULL
            )
            -- keep scenario 1+2
            AND (
                A.ID_1 = B.ID_1
                OR A.ID_1 IS NULL AND B.ID_1 IS NULL
            )
            AND (
                A.ID_2 = B.ID_2
                OR A.ID_2 IS NULL AND B.ID_2 IS NULL
            )
            AND (
                A.ID_3 = B.ID_3
                OR A.ID_3 IS NULL AND B.ID_3 IS NULL
            )
            AND (
                A.ID_4 = B.ID_4
                OR A.ID_4 IS NULL AND B.ID_4 IS NULL
            )
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    -- scenario 1+2
    directMatch
UNION ALL SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B
        -- exclude scenario 4
        ON (
            A.ID_1 IS NOT NULL
            OR A.ID_2 IS NOT NULL
            OR A.ID_3 IS NOT NULL
            OR A.ID_4 IS NOT NULL
        )
        AND (
            B.ID_1 IS NOT NULL
            OR B.ID_2 IS NOT NULL
            OR B.ID_3 IS NOT NULL
            OR B.ID_4 IS NOT NULL
        )
        -- scenario 3
        AND (
            COALESCE(A.ID_1, B.ID_1) = COALESCE(B.ID_1, A.ID_1)
            OR A.ID_1 IS NULL AND B.ID_1 IS NULL
        )
        AND (
            COALESCE(A.ID_2, B.ID_2) = COALESCE(B.ID_2, A.ID_2)
            OR A.ID_2 IS NULL AND B.ID_2 IS NULL
        )
        AND (
            COALESCE(A.ID_3, B.ID_3) = COALESCE(B.ID_3, A.ID_3)
            OR A.ID_3 IS NULL AND B.ID_3 IS NULL
        )
        AND (
            COALESCE(A.ID_4, B.ID_4) = COALESCE(B.ID_4, A.ID_4)
            OR A.ID_4 IS NULL AND B.ID_4 IS NULL
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                directMatch m
            WHERE 
                (
                    A.ID_1 = m.ID_1
                    OR A.ID_1 IS NULL AND m.ID_1 IS NULL
                )
                AND (
                    A.ID_2 = m.ID_2
                    OR A.ID_2 IS NULL AND m.ID_2 IS NULL
                )
                AND (
                    A.ID_3 = m.ID_3
                    OR A.ID_3 IS NULL AND m.ID_3 IS NULL
                )
                AND (
                    A.ID_4 = m.ID_4
                    OR A.ID_4 IS NULL AND m.ID_4 IS NULL
                )
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                directMatch m
            WHERE 
                (
                    B.ID_1 = m.ID_1
                    OR B.ID_1 IS NULL AND m.ID_1 IS NULL
                )
                AND (
                    B.ID_2 = m.ID_2
                    OR B.ID_2 IS NULL AND m.ID_2 IS NULL
                )
                AND (
                    B.ID_3 = m.ID_3
                    OR B.ID_3 IS NULL AND m.ID_3 IS NULL
                )
                AND (
                    B.ID_4 = m.ID_4
                    OR B.ID_4 IS NULL AND m.ID_4 IS NULL
                )
        )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, I also came up with a similar code, but still having the same problem even with this code, because let's say in Table B ID_1 is NULL, then it'll match ID_1 from Table A and present it as a result of the record, when the result should be NULL instead for ID_1.

Comment: @SimonWells My given solution works for the sample data you provided. I may not have understood your scenarios well enough. Please update your sample data as well as your expected outcome.